# Space between navigation bar and screen

Tags: html, css

I faced an issue today when I created the navigation bar I found a space between the screen and the navigation bar, 
[here's what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SJan.jpg)

I want the navigation bar with full width, no space at all, I tried using width `width: 100%` but it didn't work.

Here's the code :

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #141414;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

li {
    float: right;
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
}

li a {
    font-family: Julius Sans One, Arial;
    font-size: 19px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logoimg {
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <ul>
        <li class="left"><img class="logoimg" src="/images/logo.png"></li>
        <li><a>Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Test 2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it, your navigation bar **is** full-width. The additional whitespace you are seeing is actually coming from `<body>`, which adds a `margin` of `8px` by default. You can override this to ensure that your content is flush against the edge of the page:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* Added */
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #141414;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

li {
    float: right;
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
}

li a {
    font-family: Julius Sans One, Arial;
    font-size: 19px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logoimg {
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <ul>
        <li class="left"><img class="logoimg" src="/images/logo.png"></li>
        <li><a>Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Test 2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

It's important to note that the `<body>` tag is always present, even when not explicitly written. This can be seen in the snippets here -- note that the original snippet appears to be offset from the edge and the line, whereas this does not, and all I added was an override for `body` margin.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is the default window/page Padding/Margin. You can set this default value to 0 in order to have your full width/height of the page:

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This should correct your problem.